# FLDigi Crashes When Trying to Load RigCAT Description File

Tags: digital-modes, icom, icom-ic-7300, fldigi

I am trying to setup FLDigi with my ICOM-7300 via the USB connection so I can start using digital modes. Everytime I try to [follow the instructions here](http://thestingyham.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-set-up-icom-7300-for-digital.html), it doesn't work. Specifically, everytime I try to load the .xml file, FLDigi hangs up and crashes.

[image]

I tried using the Hamlib definition for the radio, and I can see it has made some kind of connection because whenever I rotate the VFO on the radio, the FLDigi frequency display changes, and vice versa when I change that frequency the radio changes.

However, I am receiving nothing on the waterfall display, and when I center on digital signals in the low end of the 40m band FLDigi doesn't decode anything. Not even a garbled signal that might indicate I'm on the wrong encoding protocol.

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to get the radio data into FLDigi in addition to the rig control features?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RigCAT. Check.
2. Commands are echoed. Check.
3. CAT command for PTT. Check.

I use Fldigi with IC-7300.

3. CAT command for PTT. Uncheck.
4. Toggle RTS fot PTT. Check.

IC-7300 Setting

1. USB Send OFF
2. USB Keying (CW) RTS
3. USB Keying (RTTY) OFF

It works well. :)

73

DS1SKU